# Change scale based on relative mouse hover distance?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the scale to increase as the mouse hovers closer to the object, and the max scale should be when the mouse hovers over the center. How can I do this using Javascript?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].setAttribute("r", "100");
}
```

```css
svg {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg>
<circle cx="145" cy="80" r="40" fill="red" onmouseover="myFunction()"/>
</svg>

<p>
  Move mouse closer to circle to increase size
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tahirjuba/2r5ufd8z/7/

Comment: Do you guys not know what I mean?

Comment: Use a `mousemove` event, get the mouse coordinates from the event object, calculate the distance, and set your circle's radius (or `transform="scale(X)"`) appropriately.

Comment: But until you post a legitimate attempt yourself, we're not gonna help much.

Comment: thanks, will post attempt soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");

function myFunction(evt) {
  var r = Math.abs(evt.x - parseInt(evt.target.getAttribute('cx'), 10)) + Math.abs(evt.y - parseInt(evt.target.getAttribute('cy'), 10));
  r += 10;
  document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].setAttribute("r", r);
}
```

```css
svg {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg>
<circle id="circle" cx="145" cy="80" r="40" fill="red" onmousemove="myFunction(evt)"/>
</svg>

<p>
  Move mouse closer to circle to increase size
</p>
```

Comment: Did you get the coordinates of the mouse and somehow apply them to 'r'?

Comment: @tjuba Yes that it what `r` does. It takes the difference between mousevent x and svg coordinate x and adds it to the difference between mousevent y and svg coordinate y. I then use the result `r` as the radius for the circle (+ 10 pixels so the circle never disappears completely).

Comment: Thanks, so what if I wanted to change what attribute varied with the mouse movement, like opacity. What things could I replace?

Comment: The first parameter of `setAttribute` is the attribute to modify on the element and the second parameter is the value to modify it to.